# How to parse a string as a list structure?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a string, which holds a a list structure like `((p X) (q (f X)))` and I would really like to find a function that interprets/converts this string as a list of lists just like if it was a `'((p X) (q (f X)))`.

`(list "((p X) (q (f X)))")` just makes it a single element list.

`(intern "((p X) (q (f X)))")` encloses it in | symbols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How does

```
(read-from-string  "((p X) (q (f X)))")
```

work for you?  Documentation found [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm#read-from-string).

Comment: God damn it! That's exactly what I need. I gave up on google too early. Thank you so much, bro!

Answer (score 3):

`"((p X) (q (f X)))"` is a string in Lisp. Strings are enclosed in `"`.

`LIST` creates a list with its arguments as elements.

So `(list "((p X) (q (f X)))")` creates a list with the string as the element.

`INTERN` creates a symbol.

`(intern "((p X) (q (f X)))")` creates a symbol with the string argument as its name. In Common Lisp symbols can have arbitrary names, even including characters like `(` and `)`. Such symbols are printed enclosed in `|`. Example: `|((p X) (q (f X)))|` is a symbol with such a strange name.

Parsing an s-expression is called *reading* in Lisp. The functions to do so are for example `READ` and `READ-FROM-STRING`.

There are two basic ways to read the s-expression:

```
CL-USER 1 > (read-from-string "((p X) (q (f X)))")
((P X) (Q (F X)))
17
```

But you can also open an input stream based on the string using `WITH-INPUT-FROM-STRING`and then use the usual `READ`:

```
CL-USER 2 > (with-input-from-string (stream "((p X) (q (f X)))")
              (read stream))
((P X) (Q (F X)))
```